# Sending Magento category pages after last to 404

Tags: php, magento

as the title says, I'm trying to send Magento category pages after the last to the 404 page, without redirect.

For doing this I built an observer that observes controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after dispatch. From that I verify that param p (page) is numeric and inside min and max.

All that is ok, but I can't forward the action to my custom noRoute page!

I can throw an exception, but it will fire the default Magento 404 page, and I can't use the _forward Magento function inside an observer!

How should I do? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to place this code in observer this will work
     Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);

Comment: I don't want a redirect, I want to display the error page in the same url where I am!